# How to use a shared_ptr from interface implementation

Tags: c++, std

Let’s say that DoSomething method is the implementation of an interface. I can’t change its signature.
How could DoSomething instantiate MyClass2 with the second constructor and provide a smart pointer to the current instance of MyClass (not a copy) ?

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


class MyClass;

class MyClass2 {
public:
  std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;

  MyClass2() {
    ptr = nullptr;
  }

  MyClass2(std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptrParam) {
    ptr = std::move(ptrParam);
  }

};

class MyClass {
public:
  int value;

  MyClass() :
    value{1} {
    OutputDebugString(L"MyClass\r\n");
  }

  ~MyClass() {
    OutputDebugString(L"~MyClass\r\n");
  }

  std::shared_ptr<MyClass2> DoSomething() {
    return std::make_shared<MyClass2>();
  }

};

int main() {
  auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
  auto ptr2 = ptr->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: [shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for this to work is if `DoSomething` has access to a smart pointer pointing to the instance of `MyClass`. You can't place a `shared_ptr` in `MyClass` because that would create a reference loop, creating a memory leak.

However, there is another type of smart pointer: `weak_ptr`. It was designed for pretty much this purpose: when you need a smart pointer, but you don't want to create a reference loop.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  int value;
  std::weak_ptr<MyClass> selfReference;

  MyClass() :
    value{1} {
    OutputDebugString(L"MyClass\r\n");
  }

  ~MyClass() {
    OutputDebugString(L"~MyClass\r\n");
  }

  void giveSelfReference(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>& sr) {
    selfReference = sr;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<MyClass2> DoSomething() {
    return std::make_shared<MyClass2>(selfReference.lock());
  }

};
```

So, then `main` would look like:

```
int main() {
  auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
  ptr->giveSelfReference(ptr);
  auto ptr2 = ptr->DoSomething();
}
```

Edit: There is a comment recommending `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this`, I'm not familiar with this, but it looks to be a somewhat more elegant version of my solution.

Comment: I've seen that comment too, it is technically really close to your suggestion since enable_shared_from_this is implemented with a weak_ptr too.
Thank you both for your help.